# jQuery-Ajax created Checkboxlist does not respond to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a radio button list (rblCategories) and when selected value is changed I create a checkbox list using ajax and populate it. I need to update my datatable when any checkbox is checked/unchecked but I can't get it to respond to to change in state.

This is what i have and what I have tried (I removed all unnecessary stuff like styling, etc.)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label for="ddlYear">Select Year</label>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlYear" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="rblCategories">Categories</label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server"
            ID="rblCategories" 
            ClientIDMode="Static" 
            DataTextField="Name" 
            DataValueField="TypeID" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="divSubCategory">
    </div>
</div>

//Using the selected values of ddlYear and rblCategories, populate table
function bindDataTable() {
    var year = $('#ddlYear').val();
    var selCategoryID = $('#rblCategories input:checked').val()
    var url = "";
    var params = "";

    // -1 refers to "All" categories
    if ('-1' == selCategoryID) {
        url = "../services/exp.asmx/GetExpenseByYear";
        params = JSON.stringify({ "Year": year });
    }
    else {
        url = "../services/exp.asmx/GetExpenseByYearByCategory";
        params = JSON.stringify({ "Year": year, "CategoryID": selCategoryID });
    }
    populteTable(url, params, tblExpenses);
}

//for testing
function bindDataTable(subCategories) {debugger
}

// create and populate sub-category checkbox list based on selected category
function updateSubTypes(typeID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/services/exp.asmx/GetExpenseSubTypeItems") %>',
        cache: false,
        data: "{ 'TypeID': '" + typeID + "' }",
        success: AjaxSucceeded,
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
}

function AjaxFailed(result) {
   alert('Failed to load checkbox list');
}

function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
    BindCheckBoxList(result);
}

function BindCheckBoxList(result) {
    $('#divSubCategory').empty();
    var items = JSON.parse(result.d);
    if (items.length > 0)
        CreateCheckBoxList(items);
}

function CreateCheckBoxList(checkboxlistItems) {
    var lbl = $('<label></label>').text('Sub-Categories');
    $('#divSubCategory').append(lbl);
    var table = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: 'cblSubCategory', class: 'form-control' });
    var row = table.append($('<tr></tr>'));
    var counter = 0;

    $(checkboxlistItems).each(function (i) {
        row.append($('<td></td>').append($('<input>').attr({
            type: 'checkbox', name: 'chklistitem', value: this.ExpenseSubTypeID, id: 'chklistitem' + counter
        })).append(
        $('<label>').attr({
            for: 'chklistitem' + counter++
        }).text(this.Name)));
    });
    $('#divSubCategory').append(table);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rblCategories input').change(function () {
        var selCategoryID = $(this).val();
        if (selCategoryID != null) {
            updateSubTypes(selCategoryID)
        }
        bindDataTable();
    });

    // This never gets hit; I tried chklistitem instead of cblSubCategory too
    $('#cblSubCategory input').change(function () {debugger
        var selCategoryID = $('#rblCategories input:checked').val()
        var names = $('.parent input:checked').map(function () {
            return this.name;
        }).get();
        bindDataTable(names);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#cblSubCategory input').change(function () {`

TO

`$('#cblSubCategory').on('change','input', function () {`

Use jQuerys `.on()` method when loading elements dynamically, which will look for any new elements added to the DOM that match that selector. Otherwise jQuery will only parse the DOM once on initial execution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rblCategories').on('change','input', (function () {
        var selCategoryID = $(this).val();
        if (selCategoryID != null) {
            updateSubTypes(selCategoryID)
        }
        bindDataTable();
    });

    // This never gets hit; I tried chklistitem instead of cblSubCategory too
    $('#cblSubCategory').on('change','input', function () {debugger
        var selCategoryID = $('#rblCategories input:checked').val()
        var names = $('.parent input:checked').map(function () {
            return this.name;
        }).get();
        bindDataTable(names);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I made the changes as suggested for both rblCategories and cblSubCategory. rblCategories worked fine, even though it was working before I made the change but cblSubCategory still doesn't work. Not sure if it is normal but when the checkbox list is displayed in browser, in response to a change in rblCategories selection, and I do a "view source" I don't see any control with id of "cblSubCategory; I only see the empty div it is supposed to be in.

Comment: I made some changes that might shed some light on the issue but not sure if I should update my original post with an "update" or some other way. Basically, I moved the onchange event of checkbox list to CreateCheckBoxList function, right after I append the generated table to div. Now, when I make a selection the function gets hit but it shows nothing checked. I also modified the code and added an "onchange" attribute to divSubCategory, and that also works; the function for onchange gets hit but again it shows nothing is selected. Maybe the way I check for selected checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

The following changes fixed the issue; However, I marked cantucket's reply as answer cause he put me in the right direction.

I added an attr line to "createCheckBoxList" function; right after I append the resulting table to div:

```
function createCheckBoxList(checkboxlistItems) {
    var lbl = $('<label></label>').text('Sub-Categories');
    $('#divSubCategory').append(lbl);
    var table = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: 'cblSubCategory', class: 'form-control' });
    var row = table.append($('<tr></tr>'));
    var counter = 0;

    $(checkboxlistItems).each(function (i) {
        row.append($('<td></td>').append($('<input>').attr({
            type: 'checkbox', name: 'cblSubCategory', value: this.ExpenseSubTypeID, id: 'cblSubCategory' + counter
        })).append(
        $('<label>').attr({
            for: 'cblSubCategory' + counter++
        }).text(this.Name)));
    });
    $('#divSubCategory').append(table);

    // added this line
    $('#divSubCategory').attr({ onclick: "onSubCatChange()" });
}
```

I added "onSubCatChange()" function:

```
function onSubCatChange() {
    // Both following methods work to get list o checked items
    var names = [];
    $('#cblSubCategory input:checked').each(function() {
        names.push(this.value);
    });

    var names2 = $('#cblSubCategory input:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    bindDataTable(names);
}
```

And I removed the checkbox list's on change handler in document.ready() function.